# How can I run 2 loops together in PHP without duplicating values?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to check MD5 of some data with md5 some files, both of them are stored in one dimensional arrays. Say I have 4 files in the $files array with the same number of $datas, the following code prints "NO DIFFERENCE" 12 times instead of 4 times.

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    foreach($datas as $data) {
        if(md5($data) !== md5_file($file)) {
            echo "NO DIFFERENCE"; 
        }
    }
}
```

How do I prevent duplicating a loop?

**Update:**
Both arrays $datas and $files contains equal number of values but the tricky part is the values in $files array starts from key number 2 (because I removed "." and ".." from scandir result) whereas in $datas array values start from key number 0.

Comment: If you have a one-dimensional array, why exactly do you need 2 loops then?

Comment: There are 2 1D arrays, what do I need then?

Comment: If you have to compare **each** *file* with **each** *data* there is no other way than you do it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Convert your $datas array to an array of hashes before the loop, otherwise you're redoing the md5 hash for each $data against every file, four times more than you need, at a performance overhead... if you create the data hashes in an array first, you can then use in_array (or better yet array_key_exists() if you store the hash as a key)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare md5(files) to the mfs5(datas) you can simply do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($files); $i++){
    if(md5($datas[$i]) !== md5_file($files[$i+2])) 
        echo "NO DIFFERENCE"; 
}
```

If you want to check if each file have one corresponding md5(datas) then you should use you double loop as you did.

Comment: Who sais both arrays are ordered the same way?

Comment: And who says he used numeric keys?

Comment: If your answer contains a question to the OP then you should use the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

> the following code prints "NO DIFFERENCE" 12 times instead of 4 times.

The reason for that is you have a nested loop.

For each value in the `$files` array, your inner `foreach` will run once.

So say if you have 3 values in `$files` and 4 values in `$datas`, the loop will run as follows:

- First value in `$files` iterated

  - Inner loop runs, and iterates through all 4 values in `$datas`
- Second value in `$files` iterated

  - Inner loop runs, and iterates through all 4 values in `$datas`
- Third value in `$files` iterated

  - Inner loop runs, and iterates through all 4 values in `$datas`

Answer (score 0):

Try this with one loop like this :

```
foreach($datas as $key => $value) {
if(md5($value) !== md5_file($files[$key])) {
echo "NO DIFFERENCE"; 
}
}
```

`Note:` The loop work when you have same no of values for both arrays

Comment: Another restriction is, that keys must be equal. Probably not working with string keys.

Comment: As we didn't know arrays exact data ,that's why i paste not with that.

Comment: @user2714639 Please post `keys` for both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback function. But then you should be clear about how exactly you will describe an algorithm of your problem.

The following sample shows how to maybe achieve it. But it assumes that the arrays are in the same order and that you don't want to cross-compare everything. Also `array_udiff` may not be the best approach for it.

```
function compare_by_md5($data, $file) {
    if( md5($data) === md5_file($file)) {
        echo "NO DIFFERENCE";
    }
}

array_udiff($datas, $files, 'compare_by_md5');
```

Sample is shown here: http://codepad.org/lYOyCuXA

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to detect if there is a difference:

```
$dataHashes = array();
foreach($datas as $data) {
    $dataHashes[md5($data)] = true;
}

$different = false;
foreach($files as $file) {
    if(!isset($dataHashes[md5_file($file)])) {
        $different = true;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($different);
```

If you want to know which files are different, then:

```
$dataHashes = array();
foreach($datas as $data) {
    $dataHashes[md5($data)] = true;
}

foreach($files as $file) {
    if(!isset($dataHashes[md5_file($file)])) {
        echo $file, 'is different', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure that `!==` is the operator you want to use to say 'no difference' ?
If you are looking for equality, maybe you want to use `===`

Second, `md5(...)` is time consuming, so extract the hash in a variable.

Third, if you mean equality, you can add a break in the inner loop to stop looping as soon as you find the equality.

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    $md5File = md5_file($file); // extract in a variable
    foreach($datas as $data) {
        if(md5($data) === $md5File) { // === instead of !==
            echo "NO DIFFERENCE";
            break; // break as soon as possible
        }
    }
}
```